# SSLEngine: Why retry the original operation in case of delegated tasks?

Tags: java, ssl, sslengine

Regarding the handling of Delegated Tasks, the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) for `SSLEngine` has this to say (in bold, in the last line of the quoted para):

> For any operation which may potentially block, the SSLEngine will
> create a Runnable delegated task. When SSLEngineResult indicates that
> a delegated task result is needed, the application must call
> getDelegatedTask() to obtain an outstanding delegated task and call
> its run() method (possibly using a different thread depending on the
> compute strategy). The application should continue obtaining delegated
> tasks until no more exist, **and try the original operation again.**

But why "try the original operation again", since a delegated task isn't an exception such as an overflow or an underflow?

Even [this sample from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sslengine/SSLEngineSimpleDemo.java) doesn't retry the original operation (please see the call to `runDelegatedTasks()`), nor mentions anything about retrying -- not sure if this is because it's an incomplete sample, only illustrating other aspects of the API.

Comment: Because the original operation could not  complete, because it needed what the delegated task does first.

Comment: Sure, but by running all the delegated tasks, hasn't the original operation completed? So if we tried the operation again, wouldn't it result in the same set of delegated tasks once again, requiring to be re-run for the second time... eventually resulting in an infinite loop of the original operation?

Comment: No, it hasn't completed, because it needed the result of the delegated tasks. If you tried the operation again, those results are available, so the condition won't recur. As a concrete example, a delegated task might consist of asking the user which of his certificates he wants to send to the server, as browsers do in some circumstances. It is a delegated task because it might block.

Comment: And in any case what else can you possibly do except retry the last operation? You don't know what's needed next. It tells you.